# Verbstellung bei Infinitivphrase oder Nebensatz bei mehrteiligen Verbkonstruktionen

Tags: verb, verbal-complex

Es ist mir klar, welche Stellungen die Verben in den ersten zwei Beispielen nehmen. Kann jemand mir sagen, welcher Satz in dem dritten Beispiel korrekt ist?

1. Ich habe das machen können.
2. Er weiß, dass ich das habe machen können.
3. Ich freue mich, das machen können zu haben *vs.* Ich freue mich, das zu haben machen können

Comment: Keiner der beiden Sätze im Beispiel 3 ist korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Es geht um eine Infinitivphrase (**Infinitiv mit zu**) mit einem **Modalverb** im **Perfekt**.

Die Frage wird kompliziert dadurch, dass ein Modalverb im modalen Gebrauch sein Perfekt mit einem '**Ersatzinfinitiv**' bildet. Bei schrittweisem Aufbau kommt man über

> 4 Ich freue mich, das *zu können*. (Präsens)

und

> 5 Ich freue mich, das *gekonnt zu haben*. (Perfekt, hier '*können*' als
>   Vollverb)

durch Hinzufügen von *machen* zu

> 6 *Ich freue mich, das *machen können zu haben*.

Da die Beispielsserie mit '*machen*' sehr unanschaulich ist, wandle ich Satz 6 in eine etwas verständlichere Version ab:

> 6' *Ich freue mich, dir in dieser Situation *helfen können zu haben*.

(Das *zu* in mehrteiligen Infinitivkonstruktionen tritt immer vor den letzten Infinitiv). [Anmerkung a]

Weder Satz 6 noch Satz 6' ist gut verständlich. In einem solchen Fall von Infinitivhäufung wird in einem ähnlichen Fall von der erwartbaren Reihenfolge abgewichen. Statt

> 7 … dass sie das besser nicht *sagen sollen hätte*

schlägt die Duden-Grammatik vor, das *hätte* vorzuziehen. Ergebnis:

> 8 … dass sie das besser nicht *hätte sagen sollen*. [Anmerkung b]

Wenn man diese Stellungsregel auch beim beim *Infinitiv mit zu* anwendet und das '*haben*' aus Satz 6 weiter nach vorne zieht, erhält man:

> 9 Ich freue mich, das *haben machen zu können*.

und in der  Variante

> 9' Ich freue mich, dir in dieser Situation *haben helfen zu können*.

Dieser Satz klingt schon erträglicher, tatsächlich findet sich im Internet folgendes ähnliche Beispiel:

> 10 Er erwähnt in späten Jahren selbst, dass er seinen „armen Eltern"
>   geholfen [habe] und froh gewesen sei, ihnen haben helfen zu können.
>   (W. A. Thomas-San-Galli: Ludwig van Beethoven, BoD S. 38)

Fraglich bleibt, ob man nicht auch sagen könnte

> 11 *Ich freue mich, das gemacht haben zu können* [Anmerkung c]  bzw.
>
> 11' *Ich freue mich, dir in dieser Situation aus der Klemme geholfen
>   haben zu können*; oder
>
> 12 ?*Ich freue mich, das machen gekonnt zu haben.* [Anmerkung c] bzw.
>
> 12' ?*Ich freue mich, dir in dieser Situation aus der Klemme helfen
>   gekonnt zu haben.*

All das klingt nicht wirklich schön, es sind gewissermaßen Laborsätze, zwar mit einigen Verrenkungen bildbar, aber sicherlich keine stilistischen Offenbarungen. Ich würde stattdessen Sätze wie die folgenden bevorzugen, welche gleichzeitig eine mögliche gemeinte Bedeutung verdeutlichen:

> 13 *Ich war glücklich und stolz, das tatsächlich geschafft zu haben.*
>
> 14 *Es war mir eine aufrichtige Freude, Ihnen helfen zu können.* oder:
>
> 15 *Es freut mich außerordentlich, dass mir Gelegenheit gegeben wurde,
>   auf diese interessante Frage einzugehen.*

.........................................

[Anmerkung a] Zum Platz von '*zu*' bei eingebetteten Infinitiven fand ich nur eine Aussage bei [deutschegrammatik20.de](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/der-einfache-satz/nebensaetze-als-ergaenzung/infinitivsatz-mit-zu/) im Kapitel "Infinitivsätze mit zu als Ergänzungssätze".

[Anmerkung b] so zu lesen in der Duden-Grammatik auf S. 481 Rz 684: "Obligatorisch ist die abweichende Abfolge, wenn es sich bei der zweiten Infinitivform um den vom Hilfsverb haben abhängigen Ersatzinfinitiv (…) eines Modalverbs handelt." Der Duden bezieht sich hier auf Fälle wie *was sie besser "nicht hätte sagen sollen"* statt *"was sie (…) nicht sagen sollen hätte."* (a.a.O.)

[Anmerkung c] zur Frage alternativer Konstruktionsmöglichkeiten heißt es ebd. auf S. 483 Rz 687: "Im Ganzen genommen ist die Wortstellung im Verbalkomplex durch eine gewisse Instabilität und Fluktuation geprägt." Es gebe dort *"viel Spielraum für Abweichungen unterschiedlicher Art."*

Comment: Es gibt ein Problem, auf das ich jedoch nicht eingegangen war und das ich hier nicht auch noch aufnehmen will, nämlich den Unterschied zwischen subjektiver und objektiver Modalität (sowie weiterer Bedeutungen von Modalität). Man vergleiche dazu "er kann das getan haben" und "er hat das tun können". Die Sätze 11(') und 12(') sind insofern nicht gleichbedeutend. Welcher der beiden Sätze was bedeutet, ist mir vorerst nicht klar, dazu ist all das auch viel zu konstruiert. Besser wäre sowieso gewesen, man hätte nur auf die Sätze 13 bis 15 verweisen können, ohne das alles hier aufzudröseln.

Answer (score 0):

> <s>Ich freue mich, das machen können zu haben.</s>
>
> <s>Ich freue mich, das zu haben machen können.</s>

Der Objektsatz

> …, **dass ich** das habe machen können.

lässt sich durch den Infinitivsatz

> …, das *habe* machen **zu** können.

ersetzen. Allerdings ist dieser Infinitivsatz wegen des *habe* sprachlich ungeschickt, Muttersprachler bevorzugen bei komplizierteren Zeitformen den Objektsatz.

Comment: Woher stammt diese Infinitivsatzkonstruktion? Sie erscheint mir sehr falsch. Man ersetzt nicht einfach einen Infinitiv durch ein finites Verb, nur weil sonst sehr viele Infinitive aufeinander folgen würden.

Comment: Braunschweig/Hannover/Harz.

Comment: Cool, danke! (Comments must be at least 15 characters.)

Comment: *Er freute sich, das hat machen zu können.* Die korrekte Form *das haben machen zu können* aus der Antwort von Ralf Joerres benutzt hier keiner. Ich glaube auch, dass es sich eher um Verwirrung als um korrekten Sprachgebrauch handelt.

Comment: @Janka: Auch wenn ich noch nicht fertig damit bin: _Er freute sich, das hat machen zu können_ ist definitiv falsch, das von mir in den Raum gestellte _... das haben machen zu können_ ist in der Tat fraglich. Dass derartige Konstruktionen gemieden werden, überrascht  nicht, denn sie sind quasi nur mit Papier und Bleistift analysierbar. Man muss jedoch unterscheiden zwischen nach dem System der dt. Sprache im Prinzip bildbaren, jedoch unpopulären, und nach dem System von vornherein falschen Konstruktionen. Es handelt sich da nicht um Glaubensfragen.

Comment: @Janka: Ich sehe erst jetzt Dein 'Braunschweig/Hannover/Harz'. Soll das heißen, dass in dieser Region tatsächlich so geredet wird? Aber doch sicherlich nicht so ein Satz! Könntest Du mal ein plastisches Beispiel dafür geben?

Comment: *Er freute sich, das hat machen zu können.* Dieser Einschub *hat*, um aus dem Präsens ein Perfekt zu machen ist hier relativ häufig. Ich vermute mal, in Ermangelung eines mundartlichen *habbe* oder ähnlich.

Comment: @Janka: Ein Satz aus dem prallen Leben würde mir mehr bringen; das mit dem 'machen' ist freischwebend zusammenmontiert, der ist schon allein wegen des Präteritums 'freute' ziemlich unwahrscheinlich, von diesem inhaltsschwachen 'machen' mal ganz abgesehen. Nochmal die Frage. Gibt es einen Alltagssatz mit "... hat + Infinitiv + zu + können", also sowas wie "hat mir echt Spaß gemacht, den Lehrer damit hat verarschen zu können" oder ähnliches?